# Automating build process with Jenkins

Tags: jboss, rhel, jenkins-cli

I have code checked out through cvs and I am using rhel with jboss. Can some one let me know how can I use jenkins to automate my build process. I have installed jenkins using yum but cannot access the gui version using the localhost url

Answer (score 0):

hi this post should help.

https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/application-management/post/Tx32RHFZHXY6ME1/Set-up-a-build-pipeline-with-Jenkins-and-Amazon-ECS

hope that helps!